# Log errors in Light switch desktop application c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

Iam new to Light switch desktop application. Can someone guide me on how to log errors/catch exceptions in light switch desktop application. It can be any error.

Comment: Tried googling but cant found answer for this.

Comment: Ok, I can confirm that it is not easy to google for a solution. I hope this question will get you your answer!